# Why multiple chromedriver instance keeps on running after completion of a test suite

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chrome driver 2.1 and Google chrome 28.
Selenium standalone server 2.31. I run a set of 350 test and at the end 25 chrome-driver instances are running.

Comment: I am using driver.quit() in tearDown function  in each of my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what test framework are using, but for me it happened with Selenium and MSTest. The problem was that the `[TestCleanup]` attribute is not executed if something fails while the code from `[TestInitialize]` is running.
Because of this, since I was calling `driver.Quit()` in my `[TestCleanup]` I ended up having a lot of server instances opened, and even managed to deplete the server machine's memory after some huge UI changes in our app.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just in case of chrome driver. It is the same with firefox driver.

If you forgot to use server.stop() or your program interrupted in between, you can use this port to start your server from next time

```
    import org.browsermob.proxy.ProxyServer;
```

Import the above.

```
    String sePortNumber = System.getProperty("WEBDRIVER_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER");
    if (sePortNumber == null) {
        sePortNumber="0";
    }
    ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(Integer.parseInt(sePortNumber));
    server.start();
```

You will get a random unused port every time.